# table view showing too many cells - IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[image]I have tableview cells with images and text. The first cell has an image (table cell 0) but the text in the array starts on the 2nd cell (table cell 1). and the last cell has text but no image.

The text array starts at 0, and the table cell starts at 0, so the first cell should have the first array of text.

Any ideas :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"RUNNING %d",indexPath.row);
    static NSString *CellIndentifer = @"CustomTableCell";
    CustomTableCell *cell = (CustomTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIndentifer];

   if (cell == nil)
   {
     cell = [[CustomTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIndentifer];
    }

    if (allLogos.count > indexPath.row) {
        [self loadimage:[allLogos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] row:indexPath];
    }
    else {
        cell.imageView.image = nil;
    }


    cell.tabledeallabel.text = [allcontent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.tablebarlabel.text = [allname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;

}
```

Comment: what are you returning for numberOfRowsInSection ?

Comment: its showing 15, which is correct.. but the text is one below and ends one after.. driving me potty!!!

Comment: A screenshot would be nice to visualize this situation

Comment: What is it about that screen shot that is incorrect?

Comment: that the text doesn't go on the first cell.. even though its 0 in the table view and 0 in the array

Answer (score 0):

You said “the text in the array starts on the 2nd cell (table cell 1)”.  It seems like you should be doing this:

```
NSInteger textIndex = indexPath.row - 1;
if (textIndex >= 0) {
    cell.tabledeallabel.text = allcontent[textIndex];
    cell.tablebarlabel.text = allname[textIndex];
}
```

Comment: thanks i have tried that and it doesn't work because I think think the numbering is ok, i think that a rogue cell has appeared at the top. Any reason why it would show a cell ?